# Using Command Line Arguments to write a program that prints items from two different txt files in columns

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

Im having a hard time writing a user-friendly code that prints the top *n* names for boys and girls in two left-aligned columns from two text files that has a random names for boys and girls(the text files contain 1000 names in both files).  what I do know is that I will need a **for** loop. The program has to handle exceptions appropriately and if the user gives the wrong number of command-line arguments an exception has to be raised and terminate.

```
    in_file = open(FILE_NAME1, 'r')
    for line in in_file:
        lst1 = line.split()
        for word in lst:
            print(word)

    in_file = open(FILE_NAME2, 'r')
    for line in in_file:
        lst2 = line.split()
        for word in lst2:
            print('    %s' % word)

    FILE_NAME1.close()
    FILE_NAME2.close()
```

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?  SO is intended for specific programming questions, not getting full programs written.  You should post code, a description of the problem, the expected program output, and perhaps a hypothesis about what's happening.  By the way, you might *not* need a `for` loop.  Use `open` to read files, use `print` to print strings, use `str.ljust` to left-align the strings, and see `argparse` or `sys` for accepting command line arguments.

Comment: +1 on the "Is this homework?" @ChrisP